# read a nfc chip after the users clicks a button

Tags: android, nfc

is it possible to start reading from a nfc-chip after pressing a button. After pushing the button there should be a message like "please hold your nfc chip close to the device..". I only see tutorials, which show how to start the application when holding a nfc chip to the device (onNewIntent).

Second Question. What if the application is already running and i hold the nfc chip next to my device? Is it forcing a destroy and then launches again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first part of your question, you could use a flag within your activity that indicates the state of your application (ready to write/message is showing, not ready to write/message not showing). YOu can find a simple example [here](http://www.mroland.at/fileadmin/mroland/tutorials/201209_NFCCongress_AndroidNFCWorkshop_slides.pdf):

```
private static final int DIALOG_WRITE = 1;
private boolean mWrite = false;  // write state

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    [...]

    // Set action for "Write to tag..." button:
    mMyWriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switch to write mode:
            mWrite = true;

            // Show a dialog when we are ready to write:
            showDialog(DIALOG_WRITE);
        }
    });

    [...]
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_WRITE:
            // A dialog that we show when we are ready to write to a tag:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Write to tag...")
                    .setMessage("Touch tag to start writing.")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int arg) {
                            d.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface d) {
                            mWrite = false;
                        }
                    }).create();
    }

    return null;
}

// You would call this method from onCreate/onStart/onResume/onNewIntent
// or from whereever you want to process an incoming intent
private void resolveIntent(Intent data, boolean foregroundDispatch) {
    String action = data.getAction();

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        // The reference to the tag that invoked us is passed as a parameter (intent extra EXTRA_TAG)
        Tag tag = data.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

        if (mWrite) {
            // We want to write
            mWrite = false;

            // TODO: write to tag
        } else {
            // not in write-mode

            // TODO: read tag or do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the second part of your question, when you want to receive NFC tag discovery events while your activity is already in the foreground, you should register with the NFC foreground dispatch system. See [Advanced NFC: Using the NFC Foreground Dispatch System](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch). There is no need to destroy and re-create your activity.

Comment: implemented both answers already! Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!